# Proxying requests with and without trailing slash

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to proxy both `http://www.example.org/foo/` (with trailing slash) and `http://www.example.org/foo` (without trailing slash) to the same URL on a local backend server.

I came up with the following solution, which indeed works:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

# Request URL without trailing slash
<Location "/foo">
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:64508/foo/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:64508/foo/
</Location>

# Request URL with trailing slash
<Location "/foo/">
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:64508/foo/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:64508/foo/
</Location>
```

However, it seems redundant to use two `<Location>` blocks. Furthermore, I noticed that after swapping the two `<Location>` blocks, the solution doesn't work anymore (either the CSS/JS don't load, or the client complains that *the page isn't redirecting properly*). Is there any more correct way of achieving the same as above?

Answer (score 1):

You only need one location block

```
<Location "/foo">
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:64508/foo
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:64508/foo
</Location>
```

This will match `/foo` and everything after it, including `/foo/`.

With `ProxyPass` you always need to make sure the trailing slash matches in both parameters, `/foo/` -> `/foo/` and `/foo` -> `/foo`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, with your config requests made without trailing slash return a 404.

Comment: Well, I'm using this exact configuration on various servers.

Comment: Is suspect the issue is caused by the backend server/webapp, also because the 404 page is not generated by the proxy server (Apache).